# Solve for real solutions for system of equations $xy^2=x^4-x+1$, $yz^2=y^4-y+1$, $zx^2=z^4-z+1$

Tags: systems-of-equations

$$xy^2=x^4-x+1$$
$$yz^2=y^4-y+1$$
$$zx^2=z^4-z+1$$

My first idea was to prove that all of the three variables are positive but I can't find a way to phrase the whole proof.

Comment: Just as an observation, $x = y = z = 1$ is a solution.

Comment: Also if you subtract one from another, you get $(x-y)(x^3+y^3-1) = y(xy-yz)$ and other two equations of the same form. That at least helps to show $x = y = z = 1$ is a solution. By the way Wolfram Alpha confirms there is only one solution in real which is this.